# Multiple IDP's for spring boot SAML Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, okta

Looking for Spring boot SAML integration (OKTA, any other IDP), able to do it single OKTA IDP. Now  need to do it with multiple IDP's. It is like  some one can login from OKTA or by using any SAML based IDP. IS there a way by which this can be achieved. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned that you already did the `SAML SSO` integration with `OKTA` (IDP Provider), extending your application to support multiple Idp's won't be an issue. Exchange your metadata files with other IDP. Your existing SP metadata could be used on other IDP. The change you need to do on the application side to configured & load those IDPs metadata files.

You can follows this link for more details.

[spring-security-saml-reference](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf)